# mininum value of a resample (not 0)

Tags: dataframe, min, pandas-resample

i have a dataframe (df) indexed by dates (**freq: 15 minutes**): (little example)

| datetime | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-09-02 16:15:00 | 0.00 |
| 2019-09-02 16:30:00 | 3.07 |
| 2019-09-02 16:45:00 | 1.05 |

And i want to resample my dataframe to **freq: 1 month**. Also I need calculate the min value in this month reaching this:

```
df_min = df.resample('1M').min()
```

Up to this point, all good but i need the min value not be 0, so i want something like min(i>0) but i dont know how to get it

Comment: did the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

assumption: datetime is an index

```
# make the 0 as nan and take the min
df_min= df.replace(0, np.nan).resample('1M').min()
```

```
            Value
datetime    
2019-09-30  1.05
```